# Problem aborting ASP.Net UpdatePanel or Telerik RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, telerik

I've been trying to solve a problem. I have a rather slow loading set of nested datarepeaters that take a couple minutes to fully render. I need to have a cancel button.

First I tried a simple updatepanel with a cancel button in an updateprogress that performed an abortPostBack. It would hide the updatepanel but wait until the datarepeater was done before you could do anything on the page.

We have the Telerik AJAX controls so, hoping they're more advanced, I've now wrapped it up in a RadAjaxPanel. This seems to have the same issue. I've even tried firing an ajaxManager.ajaxRequest back to the server and setting a bool to try and abort the databinding, but that event isn't caught by the server until the databinding completes.

Any ideas on how to get a responsive cancel to a large set of nested datarepeaters?

Comment: Have you tried loading the controls with a javascript timer?

Comment: Well, I do initiate the UpdatePanel load after the rest of the page renders. The problem is really trying to get it to cancel and redirect elsewhere on the site after the databinding has started. It's like it won't release that connection until it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can cancel the ajax request from Telerik ajax panel or ajax manager only before it reaches the server, i.e. inside the OnRequestStart client event of both by setting args.set_cancel(true).

Dick